# Android - Wifi Scan 802.11-b

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, wifi

I'm doing a WiFi channel scanning application running on android device.

Only channels within 802.11b networks shall be scanned.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

my question will be more; I can send **probe request** from android device and get the probe response. I develop an android application that measures the channel utilization.

Answer (score 0):

"Only channels within 802.11b networks shall be scanned." - No, this is not possible. 802.11b has the same set of channels as 802.11g and 802.11n (2.4G). There is no way to *selectively scan* for 802.11b networks only.

That's said, it's possible to scan every APs, then shows only 802.11b APs. How this is done is platform-dependent, but generally scan results (from any platform) should have a *protocol field* (which indicates 802.11b/g/n/a/ac) together with other fields such as *RSSI*, *Channel*, etc. The *protocol field* can be used to filter all detected APs, then display only APs which are operating in 802.11b mode.

Comment: Hi @artm, Thank you for the answers. I understand that you said;  the first I do `mainWifiObj1.startScan();`   seconds (After the scan is finished), I parse similary this list  `List<ScanResult> wifiScanList1 = mainWifiObj1.getScanResults();`